# How much open source is the Apollo program today?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, saturn-v, lunar-module, open-source

What percentage of NASA's [Apollo program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_program) is considered to be open source as of today? I mean if I wanted to replicate a lunar mission from scratch exactly the same way they did it, regardless of the cost, would I be able to build the rockets and spacecrafts, do the astronaut training etc. just using publicly available sources?

How many technical drawings are there available for the hardware? There are numerous Apollo rockets and spacecrafts including engines in various (mostly public) museums which may allow for inspection to clarify details missing in the documentation. Regarding software at least the [Apollo Guidance Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer) seems to have been open sourced on [GitHub](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11).

The [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) consists of both [open source hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_hardware) and [open source software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software). Let us try to evaluate the level of open source telling that HW is 50% and SW is 50%. Like this, a fully open sourced hardware and half open sourced software project would rate 75% overall. The subsystems should be evaluated on an importance scale, so if a mission has 5 critical subsystems (power, thermal, navigation, comms,  etc.) then each should roughly have a score of 20%.

Comment: I think the answer is "very little". Aside from things that are probably under ITAR restrictions, a lot of documentation has just been lost. Not only at NASA, but in particular at many subcontractors involved, many of which don't exist anymore.

Comment: This question somewhat related - Why not build Saturn V's again?: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/why-not-build-saturn-vs-again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most open source spaceflight missions revealed unintentionally](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49986/most-open-source-spaceflight-missions-revealed-unintentionally)

Comment: @OrganicMarble This question is a subset of that linked question. But here one could expect more detailed answer. So no, it does not.

Comment: Nitpick: the Apollo Guidance Computer source code on GitHub is not open source. It is Public Domain. Open source is a specific way of using copyright licensing, but you can't copyright license something which isn't copyrighted in the first place.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes you are technically right regarding licensing and you probably understand how open source is meant in this question. Source code that is in public domain actually in open source in the sense that its source is available :-).