# Saturn V's external blueprints

Tags: apollo-program, saturn-v, reference-request, open-source, 3d-modeling

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but I don't know where to ask.
I want to get a high quality orthographic blueprints of NASA's Saturn V rocket with dimensions and everything (I need it for 3d modeling), but all I could find was low quality images in Pinterest. Where can I find it? Is there any good source for this kind of stuff?

Comment: Good question. But questions like [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50276/how-much-open-source-is-the-apollo-program-today) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50026/open-source-hardware-at-nasa) or [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/why-not-build-saturn-vs-again) suggest no official documents may exist.

Comment: How high fidelity are you looking for? Do you need to model the internals accurately too?

Comment: @Dragongeek It doesn't need to be extremely accurate, I need it for a model for 3d animation. And no, I don't need the internals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we still have all the blueprints to go to the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21657/do-we-still-have-all-the-blueprints-to-go-to-the-moon)

Comment: @davidhammen not exactly, I don't need that amount of accuracy, I just need a high quality reference image with some measurements for modeling, I'm not going to a rocket...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Had a bit of a gander at what [NASA Technical Report Server](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/) and [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/) had to offer and found a couple things that I reckon might be helpful.

NASA created a 1/10 scale model of the Saturn V for a study vehicle dynamics and you can read the report [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19670028071/downloads/19670028071.pdf)

This gives us these two schematics.

[image]

[image]

They also created a 1/25 scale model for aerodynamic testing. (read report [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f09b/98077608b220e46d3a04d96e5f94050bff36.pdf?_ga=2.130777807.1165074929.1614689055-896777269.1610069136))(there's additional stuff in there like fin dimensions (I think) if you need that)

[image]

Some additional aerodynamic testing [report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19660017530/downloads/19660017530.pdf) from 1960 produced this schematic.

[image]

They were also looking into using Saturn V for deep space, resulting in this [report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19670029370/downloads/19670029370.pdf) schematics. (beefy ~40 tons to Mars)

[image]

Saturn V with a fairing if you want to be special.
[image]

Indicate if you need more in depth schematics and I dig a little deeper.

Comment: Great answer! Would you mind digging even deeper for some of my questions? Like [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50276/how-much-open-source-is-the-apollo-program-today) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49986/most-open-source-spaceflight-missions-revealed-unintentionally) or [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50026/open-source-hardware-at-nasa)?

Answer (score 28):

There's a more detailed profile drawing available for download at the bottom of [this Heroic Relics page](http://heroicrelics.org/info/saturn-v/as-503-inboard-profile.html). Here's a representative slice:

[image]

It used to be possible to get [an inexpensive print of a cleaned-up, white-on blue version of this, 180cm long](http://www.up-ship.com/drawndoc/saturnvprints.htm). (I have one, it's beautiful. The custom frame cost much more than the print.)

Comment: You might try looking at the gift shop at the NASA visitor's center in Clear Lake, TX (next to the Mission Control center). https://spacetrader.shop/

Comment: The site you linked says that they no longer sell those beautiful prints :(

Comment: @Polygnome  aaaaaaaaaaargh!

Comment: @RussellBorogove Exactly my thought, because now I want one :/

Comment: @Polygnome I don't know if you saw the other deleted answer; [Shady Stencils](https://www.shadystencils.com) seems to carry the prints now.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Thank you very much, that is very welcome news.